# Printing individual list objects within __str__ using .format(**self.__dict__)

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm printing a stat block for a game character object. In a previous question I was demonstrated a way to display the object data using in the `__str__` function like so:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.poisoned is True:
        status = "[POISONED]"
    else:
        status = ""
    self.status = status
    return ('NAME: {name} {status}\n' \
            'XP:   {xp}\n' \
            'HP:   {hit_points}\n' \
            'SP:   {spell_points}\n' \
            'STR:  {strength}\n' \
            'DEX:  {dexterity}\n' \
            'WEAPON: {weapon}\n' \
            'SPELL:  {spell}\n' \
            'ITEM:   {item}\n' \
            'AURA:   {aura}\n' \
            ).format(**self.__dict__)
```

The problem I want to solve has to do with the WEAPON, SPELL, ITEM and AURA variables. These items are defined in the Character object as single item lists: `weapon=[]` and so on. Using the above method returns the list object instead of the object it contains without the `[]`. I'd rater see a blank `" "` string or the list's contained object if one exists and not `[]`.

```
NAME: Bones 
XP:   0
HP:   100
SP:   100
STR:  14
DEX:  19
WEAPON:   []
SPELL:    []
ITEM:     []
AURA:     []
```

I've tried a number of experiments including replacing the `{weapon}` reference with `{current_weapon}` after defining `current_weapon = weapon[0]` which won't work if the list object is empty. That just errors with `IndexError: list index out of range`. I could generate the items at object instantiation, but that won't work as `self.item` will at times be an empty list container.

I could propagate the lists with `" "` objects but would then have to juggle them out with replacement items and keep track of this which seems very inelegant and potentially cumbersome.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around an elegant way to print the list object in the above `__str__` return as currently designed. I'm still learning Python and want to believe there is a simple addition I could append to this `return` string to do this.

Comment: The backslashes for line continuation are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. The code looks much better without them.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the list contains more than one thing?

Comment: I do not plan for the lists to ever contain more than a single item. WEAPON, SPELL and AURA will always contain an object, ITEM however will either contain a string item like the other 3 or it will be empty (as in expending a potion for example.) So the `return` method I use in the `__str__` should display the unbracketed item or a blank if no item exists in the list for the reference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using a 1-item list instead of just holding the item directly? If you need something to be "optional", you can use `None` to indicate that the player doesn't have a weapon etc.

Comment: I considered `None` but was unsure if it would cause a problem later when I replaced it with a list object. The honest answer is really "I don't know."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a local copy of your dict, and modify the values you want, before passing that on to the format:

```
def __str__(self):
    local_data = self.__dict__.copy()

    local_data['status'] = "[POISONED]" if self.poisoned else ""

    local_data['weapon'] = " " if not self.weapon else ','.join(self.weapon)

    return ('NAME: {name} {status}\n' \
            'XP:   {xp}\n' \
            'HP:   {hit_points}\n' \
            'SP:   {spell_points}\n' \
            'STR:  {strength}\n' \
            'DEX:  {dexterity}\n' \
            'WEAPON: {weapon}\n' \
            'SPELL:  {spell}\n' \
            'ITEM:   {item}\n' \
            'AURA:   {aura}\n' \
            ).format(**local_data)
```

It is probably better to do that, than to modify your attributes simple for the formatting, like you were doing with your `self.status`. Now you are just modifying temp copies.

Comment: I understand what you demonstrate with `local_data = self.__dict__.copy()`. But since these 4 references are dynamic and will be replaced with other objects as the game is played, doesn't locally defining `weapon = local_data['weapon']` create a potential conflict later when the item is swapped out for another; like when the player changes their spell to another spell?

Comment: It won't, as the copy created is local to the __str__function and will be recreated each time.

Comment: Correct. The str method is evaluated fresh each time so it reflects the current state. The local copy is garbage collected

Comment: Ahh, so even if I pass new values in later for those 4 references, when I call the object's `__str__` function, it will display the current live values. That is pretty elegant actually.

Comment: I cleaned up the status part to a oneliner too

Comment: Ohh, that's elegant! I like this. Both you and Enrico have given me great ways to approach this problem. It's hard to pick a defining answer. This is meant to be a learning project for me. Since I'm still green and learning, your method is easier for me to understand though.

Comment: you can make it even slightly more simple: the join function will automatically return an empty string if you pass it an empty string, so it can just be `local_data['weapon'] = ','.join(self.weapon)`

Comment: You especially want something like this because modifying the object state (`self.status`) in a conversion method (`__str__`) is a code smell.

Comment: This worked and I can easily understand the why of it. Thank you very much, this has been enlightening.

Comment: One unsuspected consequence of using the above method was that when I later defined `player = Character(player_name)` followed by `player.weapon = "Flame Sword"` the resultant output for the return rendered as `WEAPON: F,l,a,m,e, ,S,w,o,r,d` ... since there will only ever be a single object in `weapon` I changed the corresponding line to `local_data['weapon'] = " " if not self.weapon else self.weapon` which worked as intended.

Comment: You would need to take that into consideration if you are trying to allow weapon to be different types. It is usually best to commit to one type so that you sont create confusion down the line with what it could be at any moment.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the power of string formatting to check attributes of what it's passed in, and the fact that `self` is a local variable within the method:

```
def __str__(self):
    status = '[POISONED]' if self.poisoned else ''
    weapon = self.weapon[0] if self.weapon else ''
    spell = self.spell[0] if self.spell else ''
    item = self.item[0] if self.item else ''
    aura = self.aura[0] if self.aura else ''
    return ('NAME: {self.name} {status}\n'
            'XP:   {self.xp}\n'
            'HP:   {self.hit_points}\n'
            'SP:   {self.spell_points}\n'
            'STR:  {self.strength}\n'
            'DEX:  {self.dexterity}\n'
            'WEAPON: {weapon}\n'
            'SPELL:  {spell}\n'
            'ITEM:   {item}\n'
            'AURA:   {aura}\n'
            ).format(**locals())
```

Comment: In real code, I would probably combine this with @EnricoGiampieri's technique, but using an `@property` decorator to create the properties.

Comment: This is quite the clever trick, I like it. for the sake of clarity, the *locals* function return a dictionary that contains all the variable defined in the function scope. I only think that in @Vin Breau mind you can have multiple weapons, spells and sort, so maybe a string join would be better list indexing.

Comment: I do like this, it's very clear to understand by simply looking at it. Enrico's method is a bit more advanced and I'm not as comfortable with it as I am with jdi's method. Enrico's will take some re-reading and playing with to make sure I understand it fully though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a simple way, even if not so trivial. You can modify the string format to take the whole object and harness the power of the properties.This has the advantage of not creating a copy of your dictionary, that can be expensive for big object.

I'll give you an example that should be close to what you need:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # one full list and one empty one
        self.c = [1,2,3]
        self.d = []

    #these two preperties create a string versione when requeste
    c_str = property(lambda self: ", ".join(str(i) for i in self.c))
    d_str = property(lambda self: ", ".join(str(i) for i in self.d))

    def __str__(self):
        #you have to use the dotted version because properties are not visibles 
        # from the dict attribute
        string = "c = {0.c_str} \nd = {0.d_str}"
        return string.format(self)
a = A()
print str(a)
# c = 1, 2, 3 
# d =
```

If you are programming some kind of game properties can be a huge lifesavers, as you can use them to obtain complicated values as attribute instead of functions, creating a lot more cleaner code. They allow you to implement even check for the insertion of value, for examples that a value is positive.

#### EDIT:

Why I am using the `0.c_str` instead of `c_str`? it is because the properties are special objects that will be called only if you access them with the dot notation (`self.c_str`). They do not exist in the objects __dict__ so you can't use it. If you try to print the __dict__ you will see only the values **c** and **d**.

That's why I passed to the format function the whole object and accessed its attributes instead of passing it the object dictionary.

If you don't like the `0.c_str` notation you can escape it differently, for example keeping it close to the usual notation:

```
"{self.c_str}".format(self=self)
```

or

```
"{foo.c_str}".format(foo=self)
```

Comment: There are definitely a few things you demonstrate that I haven't learned yet, but I think I mostly see what you are doing here. In your `string =` I can see what `{0.c_str}` accomplishes in the resulting code, but why `0.c_str` instead of just `c_str`. I would like to better understand the why of that.

Comment: Thanks, that does help me better understand your method. If I understand correctly, the `0` is the same as `self` when used this way. Is that correct?

Comment: That is linked to the format function. the `0` mean "take the first object that I passed you" while using the `self` in that string mean "take the object that I called self when I passed it". It's just linked to the way you pass object to the format function (anonymous Vs named arguments)